# Is there anyone who can successfully run real time streaming with ffserver?

Tags: rtsp, rtp, ffserver

I hope to stream my video camera and audio mic. using `ffserver`.

`ffserver` says it could do such, but I just can't find any working source?

If someone knows, could you please show me how it's done?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please refer to following links:

- [Simple video streaming with ffserver](https://www.organicdesign.co.nz/Simple_video_streaming_with_ffserver)
- [Live video streaming
  from Ubuntu](http://www.area536.com/projects/streaming-video/) (the link is broken)

---

Following is configuration of my test env:

ffserver configuration [/etc/ffserver.conf]

```
HttpPort 8090 
RtspPort 5554
HttpBindAddress 0.0.0.0 
MaxClients 1000 
MaxBandwidth 10000 
NoDaemon 

<Feed feed1.ffm> 
File /tmp/feed1.ffm 
FileMaxSize 5M 
</Feed> 

<Stream test.mpeg4>
Feed feed1.ffm
Format rtp
VideoCodec mpeg4
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoBufferSize 80000
VideoBitRate 100
VideoQMin 1
VideoQMax 5
VideoSize 352x288
PreRoll 0
Noaudio
</Stream>
```

Run ffserver like following:

```
ffserver -d
```

Start video capture from web camera:

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -s 352x288 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

Now you can play your stream using any rtsp client. In my example I use ffplay:

```
ffplay "rtsp://localhost:5554/test.mpeg4
```

I just tested this configuration on my laptop. And it works fine!

Comment: Thank you for answering me.
It would be look idiot, I don't know well.
But, that's http, not rtsp. I hope to see case of useing rtsp port.

Comment: It works! You feed to http and contact to rtsp for playing. I thought it should be fed to rtsp. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you. But,, did't you test with audio?

Comment: You have to add audio codec parameters to ffserver configuration file. And add input to ffmpeg (-f alsa -i pulse). Should work!

Comment: I'm trying like this "AudioCodec aac \
AudioBitRate 32 \
AudioSampleRate 44100 \
AVOptionAudio flags +global_header" changing codecs and option but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

I also try this for video and audio but neither the video nor the sound could be established.

```
HttpPort 8090 
RtspPort 8554
HttpBindAddress 0.0.0.0 
MaxClients 1000 
MaxBandwidth 10000 
NoDefaults

<Feed feed1.ffm> 
    File /tmp/feed1.ffm 
    FileMaxSize 5M
    ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed> 

<Stream test>
    Feed feed1.ffm
    Format rtp

    #VideoCodec libx264
    #VideoFrameRate 25
    #VideoBufferSize 80000
    VideoBitRate 4000
    VideoSize 1920x1080

    AudioCodec aac
    Strict -2
    AudioBitRate 8000
    AudioChannels 2
    AudioSampleRate 44100
    AVOptionAudio flags +global_header

</Stream>
```

But by adding the "Noaudio", only the video is playing. How to fix the problem؟